# JavaScript global variable becomes undefined inside function

Tags: javascript

For some reason a JavaScript global variable becomes undefined inside function. Can't figure out why. You can copy and run the code. As you can see the global variable 'target' is defined in the first alert, but then become undefined inside the function.
Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Colors</title>
</head>
<body onload="do_game()">
<script>
var target;            
var guess_input;      
var finished = false;   
var guesses = 0;
var colors = ['blue','brown','gold','gray','green','orange','pink','purple','red','yellow'];

function do_game() {
    var random_number = Math.random() * 10;
    var index = Math.floor(random_number);
    var target = colors[index];
alert("target = " + target);
    while (!finished) {
        guess_input = prompt("I am thinking of one those colors:\n\n"+ colors +
                                  "\n\nWhat color am I thinking of?").toLowerCase();
        guesses += 1;   
        finished = check_guess();
    }
}
function check_guess() {
alert('guess_input=' + guess_input +',  target=' + target);
return true;   
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `var` from `var target = colors[index];` target has already been defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are declaring the variable again inside the function. `var target = colors[index];`. If you want to assign `colors[index]` to the global `target` then don't use `var`, otherwise it will be assigned to a local variable inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, removing the var will fix the problem.  The main issue though is that you are not assigning anything to the global target.

When you did "var target = colors[index];", you made a new local variable called target that is visible only in do_game function.  So now you had two target variables, one local and one global.  When you tried to access it in check_guess(), you accessed the global target which was still not assigned.  But if you remove the code from check_guess and put it in do_game, it would actually work.

Just wanted to explain the question of why it was happening.

Answer (score 0):

if you define any variable using var key word or without var , outside of function it will automatically become the global variable.

If variable has been defined in the body of any function without var keyword it will also work as global variable but if you define it using var it will become  local variable for the particular function

Answer (score 0):

You should add the return value of 'guess_input' to the parameter of check_guess function

```
function do_game() {
    var random_number = Math.random() * 10;
    var index = Math.floor(random_number);
    var target = colors[index];
alert("target = " + target);
    while (!finished) {
        guess_input = prompt("I am thinking of one those colors:\n\n"+ colors +
                                  "\n\nWhat color am I thinking of?").toLowerCase();
        guesses += 1;   
        finished = check_guess(guess_input);
    }
}
function check_guess(target) {
alert('guess_input=' + guess_input +',  target=' + target);
return true;   
}
```

check this out - https://jsfiddle.net/sdqyqx21/