# javascript global variable undefined when calling the function a second time

Tags: javascript, global

```
    var myTimer = 0;

    function showChat()
    {
        $('##ChatArea').toggle();

        var v = $('##ChatArea').is(":visible");

        if (v == true) 
        { 
            var myTimer = 2;
            console.log('Turned on ' + myTimer) 
        } 
        else 
        {
            console.log('Turned off ' + myTimer) 
        };
    }
```

So I have this code set up to show a section of the screen and then the same button to close said section. When I open it, I want to set a timer (Removed so as not to confuse people) and use setinterval to store the ID into myTimer (simulated by the "var myTimer = 2"). Even without that part of the code though, it still fails.

So when I open it, the console says "Turned on 2" (working as expected). When I close it, I expected it to be 2 (since I already set the global variable to 2). But what I get is "Turned off undefined".

The global variable is defined (I believe) at the very top. So what am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't turning it off show if not 2, then at least 0?

Comment: You're declaring a local variable with the same name of a global one `var myTimer = 2;`

Comment: Just set its value. `myTimer = 2;` instead of `var myTimer = 2;`

Comment: Yeah.. I just caught that.

Comment: Unrelated Question:  `$('##ChatArea')` so you're grabbing an element with the attribute `id="#ChatArea"`?

Comment: I use Lucee (CFML) which uses pounds to show variables. ## is so that it shows to the server as a #.

As far as I understood, jQuery requires a pound before the ID.

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript global variable becomes undefined inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313824/javascript-global-variable-becomes-undefined-inside-function)

I didn't think it was within the function, but this is it. Sorry guys. I didn't realize using var sets the variable.. Well, I knew it, but didn't think it would make a local one and remove the global one.

Solution, Change var myTimer=2 to myTimer=2.